# any way to see boot menu with a cracked screen?

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8, display, hdmi

I have an old laptop with a cracked screen, as in, nothing shows.

I can still use it just fine if i connect an external monitor via hdmi.

I wanted to install linux on it, but to my disappointment, i can't see the boot menu, because the lappy won't recognise an hdmi monitor until it boots windows.

So;
a) Is there any way i can install a new OS, or will i have to just repair the screen?
b) Can i even upgrade to windows 10, or will the hdmi port similarly go offline during this process?

Comment: Sometimes, they'll recognise a connected screen if they think the lid is closed. See if you can figure out where the lid sensor is & put a small magnet on it.

Comment: What Tetsujin said. The sensor is usually where your right palm or wrist sits.

Comment: @spikey_richie There are 3 common locations for the lid-sensor(s). All located in the laptop base at the front edge (the edge closest to the user). Single sensor in the middle, single sensor just to the right of the touchpad or a pair of sensors, one left and one right almost at the corners. In case of a dual-sensors BOTH must be triggered to get the lid closed signal.

Comment: no dice. i found two points that were magnetic, place lego magnets on them, it did nothing. i also set closing the lid to do nothing and rebooted, also didn't work

Comment: You don't put magnets on the lid magnets, you put them where those would touch the body as the lid is closed. That's where the sensors are.

Comment: I understood, i put the magnets where my palms would rest. there were two magnetic points, left side and right, and i put a magnet on one, the other, and then both, but it had no effect. i'm looking for stronger magnets at the moment, as lego magnets are VERY weak.